# Topology Study Books

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am interested in studying topology and in particular maps of the sphere to itself. However, I have no background in topology and I would prefer a book that avoids very technical proofs. Something like [Topology for Physcists, Albert S. Schwarz](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-02998-5) .

Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possibly [*Geometry of Surfaces*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PTNHBGAtjTYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Geometry+of+Surfaces&hl=en)  by John Stillwell

Comment: [_Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint_, by Milnor](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2017/MilnorDiff.pdf)

Comment: *Basic Topology* by Armstrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this book:

Frankel, T. (2011). The geometry of physics.
doi:10.1017/cbo9781139061377

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-of-physics/94894F70DB22055BD7BC2B84C135ABAF

It covers a lot of material with some examples and explanations. But even so, these topics are still quite technical. I think this book  shares the same “spirit” of your book.

Here is an extract of the book :

[image]

---

There is also this classical introduction book:

Lee, J. M. (2014). Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
New York, NY: Springer.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5

This one is a "math" book, but very pedagogical :

[image]

---

These are very nice theories, but you have to soak up a lot of things  and it takes time.

---